# Unwind, but keep original array in each result row

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

```
{ 
    name: 'John Smith',
    appointments: [
        {date: 'date1', type: 'type one'},
        {date: 'date2', type: 'type two'}
    ]
},
{ 
    name: 'Michael Jackson',
    appointments: [
        {date: 'date3', type: 'type three'},
    ]
}
```

As a result i need the following:

```
{ 
    name: 'John Smith',
    appointment: {date: 'date1', type: 'type one'},
    appointments: [
        {date: 'date1', type: 'type one'},
        {date: 'date2', type: 'type two'}
    ]
},
{ 
    name: 'John Smith',
    appointment: {date: 'date2', type: 'type two'},
    appointments: [
        {date: 'date1', type: 'type one'},
        {date: 'date2', type: 'type two'}
    ]
},
{ 
    name: 'Michael Jackson',
    appointment: {date: 'date3', type: 'type three'},
    appointments: [
        {date: 'date3', type: 'type three'},
    ]
}
```

Is there any form of aggregation unwind that will unwind `appointments` into `appointment`, but will still keep the original appointments array in each result record?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$addFields` to clone `appointments` in `appointment`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `appointment` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { appointment: "$appointments" } },
  { $unwind: "$appointment" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wXWt-KLfEgu)